# Does $ \ 3\mid (M_p - 4)$?

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

So I was given a challenge by my maths teacher and I do not know how to solve it:

> **Challenge:**
>
> Find three prime numbers $p, q, r$ such that $pqr(p + q + r) = P = \text{Perfect Number}$.
>
> **Ultimate:**
>
> Do not use a calculator or have any access to the internet.

---

**My Attempt for the *Ultimate* Part of the Challenge:**

Now so far, nobody has discovered an *odd* perfect number, thus $P$ is even, meaning that one of the prime numbers has to be $2$. I will denote $2$ as $p$:
$$\therefore 2qr(2 + q + r) = P$$
Now I also know that primes are always odd (otherwise they will have a factor of $2$ so then it is not prime, excluding that $2$ is prime), so two primes when added together will equal an even number, and adding $2$ to that will also give an even number:
$$\therefore 2 + q + r = \{2x : q \lor r \neq 2 \ \land \ x\in \mathbb{N} \because (2, q, r)\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
$$\therefore 4qrx = P$$
Since $4\mid P$ then this implies that $P\neq 6$ because $4\nmid 6$. For $28$, $28/4 = 7$ which is a prime number itself and has no (prime) divisors, which implies that $P\neq 28$. In fact, any perfect number is of the form $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$, so this means that one of the numbers $2$, $q$, $r$ must equal each other since $qr \neq 2^n - 1$ since $2^n - 1$ is prime (a prime of this form is known as a Mersenne Prime and it's symbol is denoted as $M_p$). We know that:
$$\begin{align} 2qr(2 + q + r) &= 4qr + 2q^2r + 2qr^2 \\ &= 4qr\bigg(1 + \frac{q}{2} + \frac{r}{2}\bigg) \\ &= 4qr\bigg(1 + \frac{q + r}{2}\bigg) \\ \therefore x &= 1 + \frac{q + r}{2} \end{align}$$
$$\because q \lor r \neq 2 \implies q + r = 2m + 1 : m\in \mathbb{N} \implies x\in \mathbb{N}$$
Here we can actually get $q$ and $r$ on both sides of the equation:
$$\frac{P}{4qr} = x = 1 + \frac{q + r}{2}$$
Now since $P$ is of the form $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$, we know that $2^n - 1$ is prime, so this means that:
$$2 + q + r = 2^n - 1 \ \land \ 2qr = 2^{n - 1}$$
Now the fault in this is that $2^n - 1$ is odd, which means that $q \lor r = 2$, and thus means that $x\in \mathbb{Q}\notin \mathbb{N}$. Let $q = 2$:
$$\therefore 4 + r = 2^n - 1 \ \land \ 4r = 2^{n - 1} \implies n > 3$$
This seems true because if $n = 3$ then substituting for $n$ in the expression $2^{n - 1}(2^n - 1)$, you get $28$ (and this was when I slapped myself in the head).

Now when I tested for $r = 3$, I got that $12 = 2^6$ although $12$ and $2^6$ have a drastic gap between each other since $2^6 = 4^3 = 64$. Also, $r \neq 2$ (and obviously $1$ since $1$ is not prime) because the next mersenne prime above $4$ is $7$, and $7 - 4 = 3$.

The next mersenne prime above $7$ is $31$, and $31 - 4 = 27$, but $r \neq 27 \because 27 = 3^3$ which is not prime.

The next mersenne prime above $31$ is $127$, and $127 - 4 = 123$, but $r \neq 123 \because 3\mid 123$ (I know from using the "divisibility by $3$ rule").

There seems to be a pattern here, where $r$ seems to always be divisible by $3$. I used the "divisibility by $3$ rule" on $8191 - 4$ and $131071 - 4$ and they seem to all be divisible by $3$. (I do not remember any other perfect numbers after that from the top of my head).

So it seems like there is no value for $r$ except $3$ itself, which is a contradiction to the fact that $pqr(p + q + r) = P$. So now I have two questions (and I am not taking the *Ultimate* challenge anymore since I am seeking help from the internet):

1. Does $ \ \exists(p, q, r) : pqr(p + q + r) = P$?
2. Does $ \ 3\mid (M_p - 4)$?

I would mostly appreciate if you answered the two questions, but I would also appreciate it if you just answered one of the questions. Although he first question is the challenge question however, I really want to know the answer to the second question. Also, did I do anything wrong in my attempt of trying to solving the challenge?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to know whether 3 divides $M_p-4$, when you don't tell us what you mean by $M_p$.

Comment: $$M_p = \text{Mersenne Prime}$$

Comment: Doesn't your posting violate the "Do not use a calculator or have any access to the internet" directive?

Comment: I know. That's the *ultimate* part of the challenge. I'm not doing it. I never used a calculator btw

Comment: Then what about the "My (Ultimate) Attempt:" start? Perhaps you should explain what the difference between "Challenge" and "Ultimate" is - maybe not everyone is familiar with the terminology.

Comment: $$2^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3 \implies 2^{2n} \equiv 2 \bmod 3\\ \implies M_p - 4 = 2^{2n+1}-1-4 \equiv 2^{1}-1-4 \equiv -3 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$$

Comment: @CatalinZara I thought I did so in the beginning in the yellow box, but ok. And also, what is mod?

Comment: $a\equiv b\bmod c$ means $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainder when you divide by $c$.